# Copied css styling behaves differently on two elements?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm still new to HTML & CSS and can't figure this one out. I have two `<ul>` lists with `<li>` elements. I created a button out of one of the li elements in the first ul list, and then copied the html and css but on hover, they behave differently. I've split them into two classes to try identify the problem but I don't know how to fix it.

Button 1 (in nav) - the whole button acts as the  element and changes colour on hover

```
<nav>
        <ul>
            <li><img src="Women in Tech-logos_transparent.png" width="150px"><a href="Homepage.html" class="Logo"></a></li>
            <li><a href="Homepage.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
            <li class="SignUp"><a href="">Sign Up</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
```

Button 2 - only the text inside the button acts as the  element and only the text background colour changes on hover.

```
<div class="IntroCTA">
        <ul>
            <li class="SecondaryButton"><a href="">Learn More</a></li>
            <li class="SignUp2"><a href="">Sign Up</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

And the CSS styling I was using on both before splitting into two

```
    .SignUp {
  background-color: #F3ED01;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  width: 150px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
}

.SignUp :hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.SignUp a {
  
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

I've created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w1daoezm/) of the code. It's probably something really simple and I'm just missing it!

Really appreciate any input or advice!

Comment: You should create a code snippet with all relevant code in here instead of linking to an external JSfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(edited)

The difference (in yours JS fiddle) is in the `li` parent elements of the `a` tags and the second `a` tag itself:  In the first case (nav menu) the `li` has `display: inline-block`, in the second case you applied `float: left` to it, which makes the applied `display: block` invalid and changes it to `block`. This changes the size of the `a` tag inside it, and therefore the size of the area that changes background-color on hover.

If you set both `li`s to `inline-block`, remove the float and add `display: block;` to the `a` tag inside it, they should behave identical.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I had used a template for the nav and hadn't even thought of that. It worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

```
.SignUp2 :hover
```

You don't need to put space there.

```
.SignUp2:hover
```

You should use that like this.

Answer (score 0):

You are styling in your list the "list" and not the "a" tag.
To fix this add a to your selector:

From

```
li.SignUp2 a
```

to

```
li.SignUp2 a
```

And add display: block; or display: inline-block;

```
li.SignUp2 a {
    display: block;


    background-color: #F3ED01;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please using the same class for applying same css